# How can I call a bootstrap modal from a Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-modal

I want to show a bootstrap modal dialog from a Controller. How can I do ?

From my _layout I'll call a modal login is_loginPartial:

```
<div class="top-bar-links">
    <a href="#" class="launchLoginModal">Login</a>
</div>

@Html.Partial("~/Views/User/_LoginPartial.cshtml");
```

In my _loginPartial view I have a partial view nested a button login by google account.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/User/_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml", new HoiCode.Web.Models.Users.ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
```

my _ExternalLoginsListPartial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "User", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div id="socialLoginList">
                @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-google-plus" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType"><i class="fa fa-google"></i> | login by @p.AuthenticationType</button>
                }
        </div>
    }
```

And from above view I'll call confirm email modal if user login by google account. Confirm email modal will be called from a ActionResult is ExternalLoginCallback

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
      return PartialView("_ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
    }
```

Comment: You want to load modal's content from server? Is that what you are asking? Or you want to have a modal already open when page loads?

Comment: @tmg yes I want to load modal from server.

Answer (score 2):

Three simple steps.

1.Add a button to your html, with attr id and data-target

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("externalLoginCallback", "account")" id="register" data-target="#exampleModal">modal</a>
```

2.Add the bootstrap modal skeleton

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. Add javascript to load content from server and open modal

   ```
   $(document).on('click','#register', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var btn = $(this);
       var target = $(btn.data('target'));
       target.find('.modal-content').load(
           $(this).attr('href'), function() {
               target.modal('show');
           }
       );
   });
   ```